# "Unable to find a javac compiler" - while trying to generate an android app with RoboHelp 10

Tags: java, android, ant, robohelp

I am exploring a trial version of Adobe's Technical Communication Suite. Following [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lq-bOranaA), I am trying to generate an Android app using a sample document.

I've tried changing the file paths for the JDK and apache.ant files, but keep receiving the same error message (see below).

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:713: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:727: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error but in a linux system and solved it by knowing that: JDK is a super command for JRE.

JRE: Java Runtime Environment only runs not compile or build (eg. using ant).

JDK: compiles and runs.

So try changing your java setting to JAVA_HOME= ..../java OR .../jdk not .../jre.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't configure your JAVA variable environment.

BTW, I don't know what IDE you are using. As far as I know, if you have more than one java versions in your computer, in eclipse you should set variables.

(1) window->preference-> left column (Java)->Compiler, you could change different compiler version.

(2) And in left column (Java) -> Installed JRE, you should also modify the JRE version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Freya. I'm not using an IDE per se, unless RoboHelp 10 counts. I'm looking to see if it's within that program that I adjust my java preferences . . .